# Azure, Angular JS, Sonar, Error Details java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: angularjs, sonarqube, sonar-runner

we're getting `"Error Details java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"` on while running **Sonar** on **Azure DevOps** build for **Angular JS** project.

I'm not seeign any error message in Azure Pipeline, but I'm seeing this error in Sonar Dashboard.

I also tried by setting follwoing variables in **Pipeline Variables Section**, but still getting same error,

**SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS -Xmx4096m -Xms4096m 

SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS -Xmx4096m -Xms4096m**

Can anyone help on this plz.

~Karthik

Comment: Are you using 32bit or 64bit Java ?? If using 32bit, change the same to 64bit and then try.

Comment: Hi @SouravAtta, we're using 64 bit only.

scanner.properties
2021-01-11T09:21:12.0177696Z INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
2021-01-11T09:21:12.1533425Z INFO: SonarScanner 4.4.0.2170
2021-01-11T09:21:12.1536413Z INFO: Java 11.0.9.1 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
2021-01-11T09:21:12.1536918Z INFO: Windows Server 2016 10.0 amd64
2021-01-11T09:21:12.1537358Z INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m

Comment: It seems like then compute engine needs more memory. Try using this sonar.properties `-Dsonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx2048m`  Change the value accordingly